# Approximate expectation of an estimator

Tags: integration, statistics

In my textbook about nonparametric statistics, we consider the uniform design model $Y_{i,n} = f(\tfrac{i}{n}) + \epsilon_{i,n}$, where $\epsilon_{i,n}$ are independent standard normal random variables, and $f(\tfrac{i}{n})$ is the function we want to recover from the data ($i = 1, \ldots, n$). Furthermore, there is a given kernel function $K: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that integrates to one.  They then define the estimator
$$
\tilde{f}_{nh}(x_0) = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i K\left(\frac{\tfrac{i}{n}-x_0}{h}\right).
$$
Now, they approximate the expectation of $\tilde{f}_{nh}$ for $n \to \infty$ by
$$
\mathbb{E}_f(\tilde{f}_{nh}(x_0)) = \frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\tfrac{i}{n})K\left(\frac{\tfrac{i}{n}-x_0}{h}\right) \approx \frac{1}{h}\int_{-x_0/h}^{(1-x_0)/h} f(u) K\left(\frac{u-x_0}{h}\right)  du.
$$
And for $h\to 0$, they say that
$$
\frac{1}{h}\int_{-x_0/h}^{(1-x_0)/h} f(u) K\left(\frac{u-x_0}{h}\right) du \approx \frac{1}{h}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)K\left(\frac{u-x_0}{h}\right)  du.
$$
When I try to approximate this integral however, I end up with something different. First, for large $n$ we see 
$$
\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\tfrac{i}{n})K\left(\frac{\tfrac{i}{n}-x_0}{h}\right) \approx\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{1} f(v)K\left(\frac{v-x_0}{h}\right)  dv.
$$
Then defining $u = \tfrac{v-x_0}{h}$, the limits of the integral become $-\tfrac{x_0}{h}$ and $\tfrac{1-x_0}{h}$, and $du = \tfrac{1}{h}dv$. So the last integral is equal to
$$
\int_{-x_0/h}^{(1-x_0)/h} f(uh+x)K(u)du.
$$
So for small $h$, we get
$$
\int_{-x_0/h}^{(1-x_0)/h} f(uh+x)K(u)du \approx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(uh+x)K(u)du
$$
Am I making a mistake mistake somewhere, or do both integrals actually coincide? Or is there a mistake in their derivation of the approximation of the expectation of the estimation?